# Dynamic tool tip in Adobe live cycle Designer ES2

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer

How to display a dynamic value in tooltip in Adobe livecycle Designer ES2?

**I have tried the following script:**

form1.page_1.flowedSubform.Table1.Row1.Cell1::mouseEnter - (JavaScript, client)
    this.assist.toolTip.value = this.rawValue;

1st time when I am hovering the mouse on the field its showing the 'field name' in tool tip

but 2nd time it is showing the right value. But I want the right value on 1st time.

**Please find the following Screenshot:**

1st time when i am entering the mouse to the field:
[image: Displaying field name]

2nd time it is giving the right value:
[image: Displaying right Value]

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution.
I was writing the script("this.assist.toolTip.value = this.rawValue;") on "mouseEnter" event but need to write script on "Exit" event of the field.
[image]
Thank you.